# OnItemDataBound registers Link Buttons in List View to Update Panels Script Manager, However, They only Work on the first click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an update panel with ChildrenAsTriggers set to true so there is no actual script manager defined on the ascx file or in the code behind file.

Inside there is a list view, whos OnItemDataBound calls this function:

```
// ------------------------------------------------
// Register Update Panel Async Postback Triggers for View Order Buttons
// ------------------------------------------------
protected void orderListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    var scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);
    LinkButton lbOne = e.Item.FindControl("viewOrder") as LinkButton;
    scriptManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lbOne);  // ToolkitScriptManager
}
```

This is supposed to take the LinkButton inside the List View, and register the buttons so a hard refresh does not occur when it is clicked.

For some reason, it only works on the first click of the link button in the list view. If I click it again, it does a hard refresh and buttons no longer seemed to be bound.

Any suggestions on why this may be?

Comment: If I put an UpdatePanel on the page without a SciptManager I get the error "The control with ID 'UpdatePanel1' requires a ScriptManager on the page". How did you get around this?

Comment: I believe its because ChildrenAsTriggers="true" is flagged on the update panel after runat="server"

Comment: Noe that does not matter. Are you perhaps using a Master page? And could have that page the ScriptManager?

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke, this is likely the case as it's an ascx file not an aspx file.

Comment: Ah, then the SciptManager is on the page itself. But that does not explain your issue. Everything in an UpdatePanel automatically does a Async PostBack. So there should be no need to register that Control with `ScriptManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lbOne)`. I cannot reproduce the issue...

Comment: So I have to do that because the control I am registering is nested inside a list view. If you just try to set inside the <triggers> tag, it says there is no control with that ID on the page.

Comment: But you should not have to register the controls in an UpdatPanel for Async PostBack in the first place, unless something else is setting it to a Full PostBack somewhere. Either in code or on the aspx page, like setting `EnablePartialRendering` to false on the ScriptManager.

Comment: Are you sure this is true to controls nested inside listviews and grid views? If so, do you know where I could read more on this?

Comment: Yes i'm sure. I can post an example but it would not be a real answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183658/discussion-between-isaac-byrne-and-vdwwd).